# Why does FOO=bar; export the variable into my environment

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

If I run

```bsh
FOO=bar docker run -it -e FOO=$FOO debian env
```

That environment variable is not set in the command output for the `env` command.

```bsh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=03f3b59c0aab
TERM=xterm
FOO=
HOME=/root
```

But if I run

```bsh
FOO=bar; docker run -i -t --rm -e FOO=$FOO debian:stable-slim env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=672bfdcde93c
TERM=xterm
FOO=bar
HOME=/root
```

Then the variable is available from the container and also exported into my current shell environment.

```bsh
echo $FOO
bar
```

I expect this behavior with `export FOO=bar` but why does that happen with `;` too?

Comment: Are you sure your examples are correct?  If I do `foo=bar` then run `echo "$foo"` I see `bar`, are you trying to do `foo=bar some_other_command` in the first example?

Comment: digging into it more it doesn't look like the ; matters until I run `bash` again. I'll clarify the question with a more concrete example of what I was trying to do.

Comment: What shell are you using? OS? Note: environment variables are listed by `env` for example. A simple `echo "$var"` prints the value of a variable (environment or not).

Comment: Please always use `-e FOO="$FOO"` because `-e FOO=$FOO` is almost always a bug.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, *FOO=bar;* does not *export the variable into my environment*

A var is set in the (present) environment only if it was previously exported:

```
$ export foo
$ foo=bar
$ env | grep foo
foo=bar
```

A variable is set in the environment of a command when it is placed before the command. Like `foo=bar command`. And it only exists while the command runs.

```
$ foo=bar bash -c 'echo "foo is = $foo"'
foo is = bar
```

The var is not set for the command line (in the present shell):

```
$ foo=bar bash -c echo\ $foo
```

Above, the value of `$foo` is replaced with nothing by **the present running shell**, thus: no output.

Your command:

```
$ FOO=bar docker run -it -e FOO=$FOO debian env
```

is converted to the actual string:

```
$ FOO=bar docker run -it -e FOO= debian env
```

**by the present running shell**.

If, instead, you set the variable (in the present running shell) with `foo=bar` before running  the command, the line will be converted to:

```
$ FOO=bar; docker run -it -e FOO=bar debian env
```

A variable set to the environment of a command is erased when the command returns:

```
$ foo=bar bash -c 'echo'; echo "foo was erased: \"$foo\""
```

**Except** when the command is a builtin in some conditions/shells:

```
$ ksh -c 'foo=bar typeset baz=quuz; echo $foo'
bar
```

Comment: The variable `FOO` is also not exported to the current shell environment, but set as a shell variable, unless it has been previously exported.

Comment: Not knowing anything about Docker, I wonder if it would actually work if the `-e FOO=$FOO` thing (which I presume is used to set an environment variable) is removed since `FOO` is set in Docker's environment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted this as a comment to the question, where Rothgar said that FOO was also "exported into my current shell environment."

Answer (score 13):

There are a number of variations to consider:

1. Just doing `FOO=bar` creates a variable named `FOO` with value `bar`, but that variable isn't passed along to new processes:

   ```bsh
   $ echo $FOO
   $ FOO=bar
   $ echo $FOO
   bar
   $ bash        # Start a new bash process
   $ echo $FOO
                 # Variable is not set in the new process
   $ exit        # Exit new bash process
   ```
2. Running `FOO=bar <command>` will run the given command with the variable set (but doesn't affect the original shell's environment):

   ```bsh
   $ echo $foo
   $ FOO=baz bash   # start a new bash process
   $ echo $FOO
   baz
   $ exit           # exit the new bash process
   exit
   $ echo $FOO      
                    # No FOO in the original bash process
   $
   ```
3. Doing `FOO=foo; <command>` is equivalent to (1); putting a semicolon between two commands is equivalent to running those two commands on two separate lines:

   ```bsh
   $ FOO=foo; echo $FOO
   foo
   $ bash
   $ echo $FOO

   $ exit
   exit
   $ echo $FOO
   foo
   $
   ```
4. Using `export` will pass a variable in the shell's environment to newly-created processes:

   ```bsh
   $ export FOO=bar
   $ echo $FOO    # Value set in original shell
   bar
   $ bash         # Start another shell
   $ echo $FOO
   bar            # Value was passed along to new process
   $ exit
   exit
   ```

Answer (score 9):

> `FOO=bar docker run -it -e FOO=$FOO debian env`

Here the `$FOO` from `FOO=$FOO` will be expanded **before** the `FOO=bar` assignment happens.

You can check that with a more straight-forward example:

```
FOO=first
FOO=second echo FOO=$FOO
=> FOO=first

FOO=third; echo FOO=$FOO
=> FOO=third
```

The `FOO=bar cmd` form will really set `FOO=bar` in the environment of `cmd`, but a command like `docker` does not automatically export its *own* environment into the container, but the environment vars have to be added explicitly with the `-e` switch.

Again, a more straightforward demo would be:

```
FOO=before
FOO=after env - FOO=$FOO printenv FOO
=> before
```

Comment: This seems to me the most concise correct answer to the question.